# JavaScript помогите разобраться в коде, пожалуйста

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста. Почему "calculateFlights(3118, true, 15000)" применяется к обоим функциям, а не только ко второй?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутри функции calculateFlights вызывается функция calculateMiles c такими же параметрами(distance,isBusinessClass).

Comment: То есть, это зависит от одинаковых параметров?

Comment: Почитайте про параметры и аргументы функций,все вопросы сами отпадут.